# Change Control Flow Programmatically in SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to jump from one to another task(in the same container) in ssis?

I tried using precedence constraint for few tasks but it seems unfeasible to set when there are large number of tasks and no of tasks changing frequently.

For example say we have 50 tasks inside a container (task1, task2,.....,task50). There's a variable, nextTaskNo, which specifies which task is to run next. 
Is there a way to write some script so that we can specify which task is to run next in the package?

Comment: you can evaluate nextTaskNo within the precedence constraint editor for each task to determine whether it should run or not.

Comment: I am already doing that but it seems unfeasible because of large number of tasks and no of tasks changing frequently[Mentioned now in the OP]. If it's possible to define in a script, that'd be great.

Comment: You can make each task a separate package, then include only one Execute Package Task within the container, whose PackageName Property is evaluated by a variable.
Before the Execute Package Task you can include a Script Task that will populate the variable depending on nextTaskNo.

Comment: Thats a good idea but for my implementation I'll need to create 50+ packages. It'll be impractical...

Comment: But you'll probably be better served by making smaller, atomic packages and having a master control the orchestration of these sub packages.

Comment: The thing is I'm adding improvements over a existing package, and It'll be a huge change in the design if I split up the tasks.

Comment: This whole approach is not a good fit for SSIS.  Task sets "changing frequently" is *not* what SSIS is about.